# How to get value of jquery appended in put field

Tags: jquery

i need to get value of jquery appended input field on keyup event

```html
<input type="text" name="days[]" class="form-control days" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Days">
```

Comment: it is working only first field

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't mentioned howmany inputs are there but from the `name` attribute is an array from your HTML, Considering that you just need to bind an event keyup to the elements that are appended.

***Note***: Use [`.on()`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to bind event to the elements which are generated on the fly. I have added both the examples of binding events.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".days").on('keyup', function() {
      console.log($(this).val());
   });
});

//OR 

  //considering your post i.e appended elements
 $(document).on('keyup', '.days' , function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="days[1]" class="form-control days" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Days">
<input type="text" name="days[2]" class="form-control days" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Days">
<input type="text" name="days[3]" class="form-control days" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Days">
<input type="text" name="days[4]" class="form-control days" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Days">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.days', function (){
    console.log($(this).val());
})
```

Hope this helps